# C: System calls and pointers to reverse a file

Tags: c

Solved. Thanks lutogniew.....just over complicating it...

So I am having some trouble with a homework assignment. The assignment is to take in a file (using only system calls), reverse it and write an output file with that reversed data on it (ASCII only). A catch is that the reverse section has to be done with pointers. I did the following below, which does work. However, it does not use pointers to reverse.

My question I guess, is how can I access something like data[] using pointers? Or, how can I read from the file into it. Everything I tried (mostly char**) only reads in null.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0; 
    int fileOut = open("output.txt", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
    int fileIn = open("input.txt", O_RDONLY);

    int start = lseek(fileIn, 0 , SEEK_CUR);
    int end = lseek(fileIn, 0 , SEEK_END);
    int restart = lseek(fileIn, 0-end , SEEK_CUR);

    char data[end];
    char reverseData[end];
    read(fileIn, data, end);
    for(i = 0; i< end; i++){
        reverseData[i] = data[end-(i+1)];
    }

    write(fileOut, reverseData, end);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: char data[end], *p = data;  I hope no one here completes your assignment for you.

Comment: `char reverseData[end];` You'd better hope your file isn't larger than the stack limit of your process.

Comment: Don't read the whole file into memory at once--read it in chunks.  And don't use lseek to determine the size of the file--use `stat`, and deal with a pipe reasonably (eg, emit an error message and abort)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must understand that what is presented to you as an array in C, in reality is just a pointer, pointing to the beginning of the memory belonging to that array. This snippet should make everything quite clear:

```
int test[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int* ptr = test + 2;       // ptr now points to the third element
```

**EDIT**

As for loading data into an array: again, remember that array itself is just a pool of memory (a buffer) - it begins where the pointer mentioned above points to, and has the size equal to `numberOfElements` * `sizeOfSingleElement`. Now look at the signature of the `read` function:

```
size_t read(int fildes, void* buf, size_t nbytes);
```

It reads `nbytes` into buffer pointed to by `buf`. Rings a bell?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at all.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I believe it gives all the background information needed to understand the problem. And answering directly would be doing homework for the asker.

Comment: If the question shouldn't be answered, then it should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

After Accept Answer.

Something for OP to consider as another approach:

For fun, a not-so-serious recursive approach to reverse the file.

```
void reverse(int fileIn, int fileOut) {
  char data;
  if (read(fileIn, &data, 1) == 1) {
    reverse(fileIn, fileOut);
    write(fileOut, &data, 1);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  int fileOut = open("output.txt", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
  int fileIn = open("input.txt", O_RDONLY);
  reverse(fileIn, fileOut);
  close(fileIn);
  close(fileOut);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for an original approach which should work as long  as the stack holds!

Comment: @ring0 Agree - Certainly this approach is severly stack limited.  But as OP was using VLAs, seems stack size was not much of a concern.